# Get contents of TTMessageRecipientField (TTMessageController)

Tags: objective-c, three20

I use the [**TTMessageController**](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_recipient_field.php) in my project.

The user can auto search
or pick a contact from his address book so that I can retrieve the
recipients from TTMessageRecipientField as NSArray.

However when the
user provides a contact that is not in his address book the NSArray
"recipients" is empty (e.g. when he just types in a contact instead of picking it from address book).

Is there a way to get just the contant string from TTMessageController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a closer look at the TTMessageController class I found a solution.

In your TTMessageController subclass use following method

```
[self textForFieldAtIndex:0]
```

returns the string value of the recipient text field.